# DOM based js updated by script loaded after DOM based code is running

Tags: javascript, ajax, syntax

If you have a js running on the parent DOM, is it possible to update that script through ajax loaded to a child div after the js in the parent started running without reloading the entire DOM.

Example:

Page A is loaded and Script A starts to run using x, y, z variables.

After 10 seconds Page B is loaded into a div located in Page A.

Page B runs Script B that changes variable y to another value lets say 8.

Script B on Page B updates Script A on Page A.

Script a is running with variables of x, 8, z.

Now is this possible without reloading Page A, while only updating Script A?

Comment: Reload the `script` without `loading` the page...

Comment: fair enough answer, but in the application I am working with when I reload the script some of the variables add onto themselves.  IE.  variable y from before the reload is lets say 2, when it reloads itself it becomes 4, if reloaded again it becomes 6.  I've tried reloading the script via jquery and also placing that script in a div and just reloading the div, both instances cause the variables to compound

Comment: Then make sure your variables are properly initialised in that A script? Or do the initialisation in script B right before you reload A?